# SSRS Map setting color property to a ARGB value using an expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, reporting-services-map

I have a [Map](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240845%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) object with a polygon layer in my report (RDL, SQL-Server 2008R2) with custom color rule ranges. The colors are set with parameters. (hex strings, ex "#FF0000").
It seems though I am unable to use an ARGB value in an expression, a normal RGB color works fine.

A few things I have tested:

```
<MapCustomColor>=Split(Parameters!segments_color.Value.ToString(),",")(0)</MapCustomColor>
```

This is my expression as of now. The parameter is a comma seperated list of RGB hex codes.
This works fine, but when I change the RGB hex codes to ARGB ones the report renders with the error. Deployment works fine.

> The value cannot be NULL.
>   Parameter name: format

I did some more testing to figure out why it won't work.

```
<MapCustomColor>="#FF0000"</MapCustomColor>
<MapCustomColor>#FF0000</MapCustomColor>
<MapCustomColor>#88FF0000</MapCustomColor>
```

These work fine, the last one uses the expected transparency.

```
<MapCustomColor>="#88FF0000"</MapCustomColor>
```

This results in the error above.

I also tried using custom code and return a string, but it shows the same behavior.

Is this some sort of bug or am I missing something? Is there any other way to set a ARGB value with an expression/parameter?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to use comma separated color values inside a single color tag. The resulting code should follow this format:

```
<MapCustomColor>#FF0000</MapCustomColor>
<MapCustomColor>#00FF00</MapCustomColor>
<MapCustomColor>#0000FF</MapCustomColor>
```